# flutter: BehaviorSubject not rebuild widget

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I am trying to use Rxdart on my statless widget:

```
class SimplePrioritySelectWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BehaviorSubject<List<String>> _valueNotifier =
      BehaviorSubject<List<String>>.seeded([]);
```

I wrap my widget by StreamBuilder:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _valueNotifier.stream,
      initialData: options,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("rebuild");
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.h,
              ),
```

I have a custom drop down widget, I don't know why, when I add a string inside `_valueNotifier` the builder method not called? and my widget not rebuilded? What is wrong?

```
  CustomDropdown(
    dropdownMenuItemList: options,
    enableBorderColor: Color(PRIMARY_COLOR_2),
    onChanged: (value) {

      _valueNotifier.value.add(value);
    
    },

  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree that the
you need to use `sink` in `_valueNotifier`

```dart
  CustomDropdown(
    dropdownMenuItemList: options,
    enableBorderColor: Color(PRIMARY_COLOR_2),
    onChanged: (value) {
      _valueNotifier.sink.add([value]);
    },

  ),
```

Comment: When I am using sink I got this error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`  @SamiKanafani

Comment: Edited the answer, your BehaviourSubject data expects `List<String>` however you are passing a String, you can pass a [value] or change the BehaviourSubect<String>

Answer (score 0):

Mutating the value won't notify `BehaviorSubject` of anything.  In order to make `BehaviorSubject` notify its listeners, you need to provide a different state object.

```dart
  CustomDropdown(
    dropdownMenuItemList: options,
    enableBorderColor: Color(PRIMARY_COLOR_2),
    onChanged: (value) {
Sta
      _valueNotifier.value = [..._valueNotifier.value, value];
      // or _valueNotifier.add([..._valueNotifier.value, value]);
    },

  ),
```

Also, a `BehaviorSubject` is state and should not be created in a `StatelessWidget`.  If you try anyway, the subject will be created (with the same initial value) every time your widget is rebuilt.